# How can I left join two unrelated tables using JPA Criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

Here I have two tables `users` and `orders`, `users` has two fields `first_name` and `last_name`, and `orders` has a field `full_name`. For some reason, I cannot change the database schema.

Now I have a query:

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.full_name = CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name)
```

And I need convert this into JPA Specifications because it is a part of other specifications. The following is my try:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class User {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
class Order {
    @Id
    private Integer orderId;

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;
}
```

The problem is, what should I fill in the following statement for the first parameter

```
(root, query, criteraBuilder) -> {
  Join<User,Order> join = root.join(???,JoinType.LEFT);
  join.on(blablabla_condition)
}
```

Is this doable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to go down the route you are trying to implement, you'll have to map the association within the `User`/`Order` as a `@OneToOne` or `@OneToMany` lazy association based on whether there can be multiple orders for a user or not. For that you'll have to map the join operation that is the complicated logic you have mapped in the native query at the top. I suggest you take a look in the [@JoinFormula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-JoinFormula) and [@JoinColumnOrFormula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-JoinColumnOrFormula) as ways to map that join.

Comment: Thanks. Never knew Joinformula, very interesting. Will give it a try

Comment: If you find this answer helpful you can upvote and/or accept it

Answer (score 0):

First attempt... 
What if you make a method with your native query?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN orders o ON o.full_name = CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name)", nativeQuery = true)
List<User> getUserJoinedWithOrder();
```

**UPDATED**

```
Specification<One> p = (user, query, cb) -> {
    return cb.equal(
            query.from(Order.class).get("fullName"), 
            cb.concat(user.get("firstName"), cb.concat(" ", user.get("lastName"))));
};

List<One> list = oneRepo.findAll(p);
```

Comment: I need specifications because I am building a complex query of which this is a part

Comment: thank you for this. But what I need is left outer join, because left outer join can join two tables as one where I can put additional conditions even some calculations, not just a specification to find a user.

Comment: @haohaolee I think with JPA it's not impossible, to make a join it need a field to related object...